# Destructure a dictionary of complex objects

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

According to [Serilog's documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#collections), it's possible to log a dictionary, and serilog will destructure it, including in-depth destructuring of objects.

If that's the case, does anyone have an idea why the following code doesn't work as expected :

```
public class ActionLoggingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public ActionLoggingAttribute(ILogger<ActionLoggingAttribute> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ActionArguments.Count > 0)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Request parameters: {@parameters}", new Dictionary<string, object>(context.ActionArguments));
        }
    }
}
```

results in the following output:

```
{... "MessageTemplate":"Request parameters: {@parameters}","Properties":{"parameters":"[newCard(key), Namespace.ClassNameInsteadOfTheActualObject(value)]" ...}}
```

Questions :

1. It looks like an array, not like a dictionary. Why? Also it contains quotation marks.
2. Why is the object isn't being destructured as well?

Comment: most C# JSON libraries serialize a dictionary into an object with properties, where a property equals a key inside the dictionary. It's smaller and less verbose than `[{ "key": "someKeyname", "value": 1234}, { ... }]`

Comment: If so, I'd expect it to be serialized as `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`.
In my case `newCard` is the key and the object not being serialized properly is the value. As it is now, it just looks as it was serialized as an array.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a bug in the _Serilog.Extensions.Logging_ adapter (which connects ASP.NET Core's logging with the Serilog provider).  The code as written should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me Nicholas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT :*** The author of Serilog just responded that it might be a bug.

Anyway - I eventually ended up iterating through the dictionary manually.

Here's the code if anyone is interested :

```
var paramsMessageToBeLogged = "Request parameters : ";
var paramsList = new List<object>();

foreach (var param in context.ActionArguments)
{
    paramsMessageToBeLogged = paramsMessageToBeLogged + string.Format("{{@{0}}} ", param.Key);
    paramsList.Add(param.Value);
}

_logger.LogInformation(paramsMessageToBeLogged, paramsList.ToArray());
```

If anyone has a better suggestion, that'll be great. Meanwhile - this works.